# Nest/Group an array of objects by attribute, ignoring null/undefined and using additional property as label

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to nest-group an array of objects.

The function provided by this gist almost works as intended and uses lodash as basis:

https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/9837596

```
const _ = require('lodash');

function nest(seq, keys) {
    if (!keys.length) return seq;
    let [first, ...rest] = keys;
    return _.mapValues(_.groupBy(seq, first), value => nest(value, rest));
}
```

This recursively,

However, there are two problems I face.

1. if a parameter is set to `null` or `undefined`, it is used as a group, instead the
2. an optional object attribute should be used as the final object key, so there are only objects, no arrays. This attribute always has to be unique in order to work correctly.

Is it possible to combine or extend the existing `nest` function to solve the above points?

The pros of this method is, that instead of the keys, I can also use an array of functions (`p => p.parameterGroup1`) to return the parameter. So instead of a last optional parameter, I could also use `p => p.parameterGroup1 ? p.parameterGroup1 : p.label`

I prepared a little test, to give you a better idea of what is expected:

```
test('nest array of objects by groups as keys, stopping at null and using a final label param', t => {
    let properties = [
        {
            parameterGroup1: 'first',
            parameterGroup2: 'second',
            parameterGroup3: 'third',
            label: 'A'
        },
        {
            parameterGroup1: 'first',
            parameterGroup2: 'second',
            parameterGroup3: null,
            label: 'B'
        },
        {
            parameterGroup1: 'a',
            parameterGroup2: 'b',
            parameterGroup3: undefined,
            label: 'C'
        },
    ]
    let expected = {
        first: {
            second: {
                third: {
                    A: {
                        parameterGroup1: 'first',
                        parameterGroup2: 'second',
                        parameterGroup3: 'third',
                        label: 'A'
                    }
                },
                B: {
                    parameterGroup1: 'first',
                    parameterGroup2: 'second',
                    parameterGroup3: null,
                    label: 'B'
                }
            }
        },
        a: {
            b: {
                C: {
                    parameterGroup1: 'a',
                    parameterGroup2: 'b',
                    parameterGroup3: undefined,
                    label: 'C'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    let grouped = nest(properties, ['parameterGroup1', 'parameterGroup2', 'parameterGroup3'], 'label')
    t.deepEqual(grouped, expected)
})
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it in vanilla js. We construct the `result` object by `reduce`ing the array `seq`: For each object `obj` in the array `seq`, we walk the `result` object level by level using the values from `obj` of the keys from `keys`. If the value is `null` or `undefined`, we skip (won't go down another level). If the value exist we go down a level, creating a level (object) if it doen't already exist. We do that repeatedly using a `reduce` on the `keys` array untill we find the leaf object (last level), to which we assign our current object under the key obtained evaluating `obj[last]`:

```
function nest(seq, keys, last) {
    return seq.reduce((result, obj) => {
        // First we find the (last level) object to which we will assign our current object to, as a child
        let lastLevel = keys.reduce((res, key) => {               // for each key in keys
            let value = obj[key];                                 // get the value from our current object obj for that key key
            if(value == null) return res;                         // if the value is null or undefined, skip
            if(res[value]) return res[value];                     // if the level for value exists return it
            return res[value] = {};                               // if it doesn't, create a new level, assing it to result and return it
        }, result);

        // then we assign it using the value of the key last
        lastLevel[obj[last]] = obj;                               // we found the last possible level, assign obj to it under the key obj[last]

        return result;
    }, {});
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function nest(seq, keys, last) {
    return seq.reduce((result, obj) => {
        let lastLevel = keys.reduce((res, key) => {
            let value = obj[key];
            if(!value) return res;
            if(res[value]) return res[value];
            return res[value] = {};
        }, result);
        lastLevel[obj[last]] = obj;
        return result;
    }, {});
}



let properties = [{parameterGroup1: 'first',parameterGroup2: 'second',parameterGroup3: 'third',label: 'A'},{parameterGroup1: 'first',parameterGroup2: 'second',parameterGroup3: null,label: 'B'},{parameterGroup1: 'a',parameterGroup2: 'b',parameterGroup3: undefined,label: 'C'}];

let grouped = nest(properties, ['parameterGroup1', 'parameterGroup2', 'parameterGroup3'], 'label');
console.log(grouped);
```